# Display maximum number of fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-files

When adding a node it only displays one upload field at a time, however I allow for 3 images to be uploaded per node, so I would like to display this maximum number fields to the user adding the node.

Comment: You'll have to override the core file widget to do that; it's no small task I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I found for this was using plupload.